# If a sphere is cut by two different planes, dividing it into sections, how many sections is it possible to end up with?

Tags: geometry

I was doing ACT prep and I came across this problem [image: ACT Problem]

The correct answer given was D, 3 or 4 only.

I selected answer choice E.

Is there any reason why the two planes couldn't be placed directly on top of each other creating two sections out of the sphere, or does that not constitute as "two different planes"?

Comment: The "different" in "two different planes" is precisely to exclude that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide the sphere with the first plane, you will end up with two sections.

If your second plane intersects the first plane outside the sphere, both planes will divide the sphere into three sections. If your second plane intersects the first plane *inside* the sphere, you'll end up with four.

The only way you could end up with two sections is if the planes were the same, which the question states that they cannot be.